# Limit notation question. Book: "Mathematics for Physicists"

Tags: calculus

A little bit ashamed to ask what is most likely a very basic thing, but I've never encountered such notation, and I also didn't find it in the book itself at least in the vicinity of the first encounter.

The book is: "Mathematics for Physicists" by P. Dennery and A. Krzywicki.
The topic is limits, in this case, limits of functions of real variable:
[image]

What does D at the start of the expression mean? It's the first time I see such a thing. Does that mean approaching from the right/left? Does it mean something else?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: It just means "derivative". $\text{D}$ is an uncommon, but still known, notation for derivative. Hence, that means $g'(x_0)$ (from the right or left). However, I find this notation with $\pm$ horrible.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Thanks. You should post this as answer.

Comment: It's a definition, so the expression on the left-hand side is *defined* to mean whatever is on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not be afraid. The $D$ is just some notation for the derivative that is not that commonly used. $Dg(x)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x)$. I've seen it in the context of calculus with several variables, where it means the Jacobian matrix. The $\pm$ does mean left or right, I think